# how can I get the cpu information for openstack flavor using libcloud?

Tags: python, openstack, openstack-nova

I prefer to use [apache-libcloud](http://libcloud.apache.org/) instead of [openstack python API](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-novaclient/api.html) to access openstack instance.

How can I get the flavor's vcpu information using libcloud ?

```
#nc= get_openstack()
flavors = nc.list_sizes()
for flavor in flavors:
    print flavor.id, flavor.name, flavor.ram, flavor.disk, flavor.bandwidth
    # print flavor.vcpus # this is not supported.
```

It is supported in Openstack API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This information is now supported in libcloud API (ver - 0.13) driver for openstack. You can call `flavor.vcpus` to get the vCPU information.

Comment: does it support all release of openstack ?

Comment: I have used it from folsom release onwards and it is working alright. I am not sure about its compatibility prior to folsom release.